# Why does my dvd player eject spontaneously

Tags: windows-10, dvd, eject

Why does my dvd player eject spontaneously even while playing a dvd? This happens on Windows10, and a restart sometimes seems to fix the problem temporarily. I have searched google for this problem, but found no answers. I tried to have the dvd player device opened in total commander, in the assumption that a player will NOT eject while the player is in use, but that did not prevent the eject.
The dvd in question is without any scratches.
I found a suggestion to switch off AutoPlay, but that was already off. And that only has effect when INSERTING a dvd, not during playing.
What I need is that the player will NOT eject while playing a dvd. For some DVD's this happens every 10 minutes or so, and when I restart from the point it ejected, it plays for another 10 minutes. This leads me to believe there is nothing wrong with the DVD in question, otherwise it would eject at the same point every time.
I did NOT replace the drive: I have only one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the drive?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure, like a loose drivebelt.